# English to German Question

Tags: translation, english-to-german, english

Perhaps some of our German speakers can be of assistance. I want to name an iTunes playlist but I am unsure of the German translation.

If I want to say "Music for a Habsburg Day," would I say MUSIK FüR EINES HABSBURGER TAGES or 
MUSIK FÜR EINEN HABSBURGERTAG or yet still, MUSIK FÜR AN EINEN HABSBURGERTAG (or something else entirely).

I think I am having trouble using the dative and genitive cases.

Answer (score 2):

Von den drei Alternativen, die Du in der Frage genannt hast, ist

"MUSIK FÜR EINEN HABSBURGER TAG"

deutlich am besten. Die anderen beiden sind grammatikalisch falsch.

Zur Begründung: Es liegt an der Präposition "für". Zu der gehört immer der Akkusativ.

https://easy-deutsch.de/prapositionen/praepositionen-mit-akkusativ/

https://easy-deutsch.de/nomen/kasus/akkusativ/

---

In English: "MUSIK FÜR EINEN HABSBURGER TAG" is correct.
Reason: The preposition "für" is always used with the "Akkusativ".

The hyperlinks above give more information about the "Akkusativ".

Comment: This may be grammatically correct but very unidiomatic.

Comment: Very good. Thanks much. (or Sehr gut, vielen dank).